# font-family: "Shojumaru",cursive,Arial,serif; , is not displaying correctly on IE

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I have defined the following CSS rule for my asp.net MVC web application :-

```
.navbar-brand {
    font-family: "Shojumaru",cursive,Arial,serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 120px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

On Firefox and chrome the result will be as follows:-

[image]

While on IE the result will be without the "fancy" effect :-

[image]

On Chrome and Firefox the font effect is displayed correctly however IE will show a different font. How can I make the font exactly the same on all browsers (if possible)?

Comment: How are you including the font? If it's the google font, you seem to be missing the font definitions entirely [Google Font Shojumaru](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Shojumaru)

Comment: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: Also, `cursive,Arial,serif` are three different variants of fonts--cursive, sans-serif and serif

Comment: @ted  i have commented this "/*@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shojumaru);*/" inside my CSS file , to stop requesting data from external website ,, maybe this caused the variance ? not sure if i can download and include this font ?

Comment: That would be your problem. Firefox is defaulting to cursive, IE to Arial

Comment: @j08691 i am using  IE 10

Comment: why IE did not do the same ? i mean the effect on firefox and chrome is fine ...

Comment: You can download it from google, but you will only get the .ttf file. You would then need to convert it to the various formats used by different browsers and include those files and write the necessary CSS. Is there a reason it can't be used/loaded from google? To make IE look like your firefox example, change the font-family to `"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif`

Comment: for performance issues mainly,i noticed that the web page keeps loading for .5 second on each request.. also i am working on an intranet web application,, so you might access the web application without internet access ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70861/discussion-between-ted-and-john-g).

Answer (score 0):

at the first you should embedding your custom font in css file with @font-face 
after that for fixed show your font currently in IE use this method :

```
 src: url('../font/Shojumaru.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
```

for example :
 `@font-face {font-family: 'Yekan';
    src: url('../font/Shojumaru.eot');
    src: url('../font/Shojumaru.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/Shojumaru.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/Shojumaru.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shojumaru, it should show you `src: url(https://...).woff2` to include in your stylesheet's `@font-face` as well as the `unicode: U+xxx` codes to include. It worked for me when I added both to my CSS file.